# How to connect GCP API gateway to the GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, api-gateway, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have configured GCP API gateway, but it is not able to connect back to GKE service.
Is there any alternate solution ?

What about GCP cloud endpoint? can we achieve same scenario by cloud endpoint?

Or should we require in both case to use internal or external load-balancer with our GKE service ?